# Option to boot from live USB doesn't show up in GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

I have a problem with Kubuntu. I can't start the system because I moved the directory `bin`, and I need to boot from a USB or DVD with an image of Kubuntu to repair it, but in GRUB the option to boot from USB doesn't appear. Can somebody help me?

Comment: On most machines you press a key when you boot to override defaults and be asked what to boot. On my dell & hp machines it's either f9 or f12, however that option can be disabled in the bios/uefi configuration.  It's machine specific (the bios used in the machine controls the keys to press)

Comment: Questions like this are usually closed as off topic here because it's not really anything to do with (K)ubuntu itself or even the bootloader, rather the firmware on your device. You should ask this question on [SU] giving the make and model of your device.

Comment: aaah, i will try there. thk

Answer (score 1):

The install of GRUB on your computer cannot be easily used to boot from a live USB. You will need to open your device firmware or boot menu and set the USB drive containing your live Linux install as the first boot option.

Most PC BIOS menus can be reached by spamming either the "F10", "F12", or "DEL" keys during startup. Depending on the manufacturer of your device, you may have to try a combination of timings and keypresses to successfully enter the BIOS settings. Once there, you can change boot options under the "Boot Options" (or something similar).

As a side note, most devices have the "F11" key set as the boot menu key.

Comment: This worked for me. Also I was able to boot directly into the live USB from BIOS under a “direct boot” heading for my ASUS motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

### Boot ISO File on USB from Desktop grub

You can boot an ISO on USB by using your desktop grub to loop mount it.
Add the following menuentry, (or similar), to /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" {
    set root=(hdx,1)
        loopback loop /Ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/Ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso splash --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
    }
```

Were x is the USB drive number.

Then in Terminal run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can add a ext4 persistent partition labeled casper-rw if you want persistence, then add a space and the word "persistent" to grub.cfg after "splash --"

### Boot Full Install on USB from Desktop grub

You can also boot a Full install USB using your desktop's grub.

Copy your preferred menuentry from your USB's grub.cfg to /etc/grub.d/40_custom on your internal drive.

Then in Terminal run:

```
sudo update-grub
```